# Why doesn't my array print out my input?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make an app that asks the user to input the number of items in an array, and then ask them to fill up that array with integers. And after, to print it out.

When I run it it asks me to input, but then gives me:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at main.main(main.java:13)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input number of units in array: ");
    int i1 = scan.nextInt();
    int[] arrayOne= new int[i1];

    for(int i=0 ; i<=i1 ; i++){

        System.out.println("Enter " + i + " unit in array.");
        arrayOne[i] = scan.nextInt();

    }


    System.out.println(arrayOne);


}

}
```

Can you guys help me spot where my mistake is? I tried a few different things, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: `i<=i1` is wrong. That would be the length of your array, not the last valid index. Use `i<i1` instead.

Comment: Your for-loop's condition check should be 'i < i1', when i == i1, it attempts to grab (for instance) index 10 in a 10 element array. Since array indices are zero-based, this is not a valid index

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044578/java-arrayindexoutofbounds-exception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays are zero based. Here you're exceeding the upper bound. Replace:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= i1; i++) {
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++) {
```

Also use [Arrays#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29) to display the array contents, otherwise the [Object#toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) representation of the array will be displayed:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOne));
```

Comment: Gives me this as an output, but no more error so that's good.

[I@43fee2db

Comment: You're displaying the `Object#toString` representation of the array. Use `Arrays.toString` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems like you need to make a new scan each time in your loop.

You are also doing one iteration too many (compared to the size of your array).

Probably this code will work better:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number of units in array: ");
        int i1 = scan.nextInt();
        int[] arrayOne= new int[i1];
        for(int i=0 ; i<i1 ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter " + i + " unit in array.");
            Scanner other_scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            arrayOne[i] = other_scan.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0 ; i<i1 ; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("arrayOne["+i+"]: "+arrayOne[i]);
        }       
    }
}
```