# I can't input values to the array

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What dimensions do you need");
    int z = input.nextInt();
    int y = input.nextInt();
    int[][] x = new int[z][y];
    for (int i = 0; i <= z; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
            System.out.println("What number do you want in " + i + " , "
                    + j);
            x[i][j] = input.nextInt();

        }
    }
```

After i reach a specific dimension, the program stops. if i enter the dimensions (1,1), it won't let me add values to (1,1); i can only input values for 0,0 and 0,1. How can i solve this?

Comment: Is it giving you an error when it stops? Try searching for that (either on this site or in Google at large).

Comment: Also, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: In you for loops, don't you want `i < y`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044578/java-arrayindexoutofbounds-exception)

Comment: Note to high-rep users: I'm sure you're aware that this question has been asked and answered repeatedly on this site. Please vote to close as duplicate instead of posting yet another answer saying the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays start at `0`. You need less than, not less than equal. Change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= z; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
```

and dimensions `1,1` would be space for a single array of length 1 containing an array of length 1. Increase the size of any dimension to add more than one value.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you alloced less memory for your array.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= z; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= y; j++) {
```

It should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in most programming languages have `0` based indices.

This means that a `int[+ a = new int[2]` has two elements at index 0 and 1. So `a[0]` is a valid index, `a[1]` is valid too but `a[2]` is not. In addition this means that when you iterate over an array you don't need to use `<=` but `<` as condition on the index, because, for example

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
```

will iterate for values of `i = 0, 1, 2, 3`, but 3 is an invalid index in a `new int[3]`, so you need to do `for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)`.