# How to properly solve this : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: java, if-statement

I am not sure how to set this properly without getting the error of

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

```
int row=table_1.getSelectedRow();
int column=4;                                
// If I put it here I get the error and won't run at all the if below   
// String tableRoCol = table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();                                                   
if (row==-1 ) { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a room to continue!");                               
}                               
// If I put it here I get the error after it run    
// String tableRoCol = table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();                               
String tableRoCol = table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();                          
if ( tableRoCol.equals("Booked")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a room that is Free to continue!");                              
} else {
    column =3;                                   
    String tableColRoom = table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();
    System.out.println("THE room ID IS :"+tableColRoom);                                
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044578/java-arrayindexoutofbounds-exception ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044578/java-arrayindexoutofbounds-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understood correctly, but i'm assuming you don't want to execute the rest of the code if row==-1, if that's the case, just wrap the rest of the code in an else block.

```
int row=table_1.getSelectedRow();
int column=4;                                

if (row==-1 ) { 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a room to continue!");                               
}
else {
    String tableRoCol = table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row, column).toString();                          
    if ( tableRoCol.equals("Booked")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a room that is Free to continue!");                              
    } else {
        column =3;                                   
        String tableColRoom = table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row,       column).toString();
        System.out.println("THE room ID IS :"+tableColRoom);                                
    }  
}
```